# Ajax page not calling with outside alert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have run Ajax code for calling another page but I face one issue. If `alert('hello')` below of ajax code then its return(response) value from another page but if I remove that alert then ajax does not send response. Means this Ajax code does not work without `alert('hello');`

**CODE**

```
function getDefaulteditDataFun()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
         type: "POST",
         url: "defaulteditdata.php",
         data: '',
         cache: false,
         success: function(res)
         {
            alert(res);
         } 
     });
  alert("hello");
} 
getDefaulteditDataFun();
```

Comment: **success: function(res){var aa=res;}** working?

Comment: success fun run but cant getting response without alert('hello')

Comment: what type of data you sending from sever? either json or html or something else..?

Comment: What error you are getting from console?

Comment: try like this res.responseText..

Comment: no, its send undefined

Comment: after calling ajax are you redirecting anywhere?

Comment: yes. but another ajax code run on document.ready

Comment: show complete code please..

Comment: I have calling getDefaulteditDataFun(); on click of submit button.

Comment: just for testing purpose, try to call the function on page load. I think, your ajax call is fired before entire document is loaded.

Comment: The code is run, it was problem about submit button. so I have change it button instead of Submit. Thanks friends.. for sending reply.

Answer (score 0):

Then try like this,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax
        ({
             type: "POST",
             url: "defaulteditdata.php",
             data: '',
             cache: false,
             complete: function(res)
             {
                alert(res.responseText);
             } 
         });
});
```

Comment: You probably have a PHP Fatal error in defaulteditdata.php.  Try checking your server/Apache log